# Removing the default author for PDFs

Tags: pdf

This is a real nit that I I'm picking :-).

I save a lot of stuff from the web as PDF files. Is there any way to not have the "Save as PDF" use my name as the author of the PDF by default, other than removing myself from my address book? I'll fill it in for those few times that I really am the author.

On OS X 10.6.4.

Comment: This has always bugged me too, I think because I feel like I'm taking credit for someone else's work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nit picking there! :)

It’s a complicated one, but I believe that it *might* be possible to experiment with:

Automator (have an action that takes a PDF and modifies it’s metadata)

PDF Services (have a service that is “Save As My AuthorLess PDF”) ;)

AppleScript (Both/All of the above)

I suggest you google around those concepts. [This](http://www.jms1.net/osx-pdf-services.shtml) is a good starting point. All in all, the idea of your script is to use the Automator’s action called: “Set PDF Metadata” (you could then put blank data on purpose):

[image: Automator Action]

If you create a PDF Service capable of replacing the default one, but that also sets the metadata to Blank, you’ve won.